# Plugin won't load error in Chromium

Tags: flash, chromium

I have the flash plugin but randomly the plugin won't load. This is especially prevalent on youtube. How do I solve this?

Comment: Why are you still using Flash for Youtube? The default is HTML5 and has been for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium usually does this when it's out of date. So just update Chromium and that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it and as said above I switched to html5 and it worked.

Comment: @AJBillson If an answer solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey check button on its left. You learn more about these things on our little [tour] page. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.